# Multi module maven project release with git on Windows

Tags: git, maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin, git-bash

I configured the maven2 release plugin in `pom.xml` for a multi module maven project. The project is located in a single git repo. Releasing process does not work on Windows.

Under *git bash* I always get `fatal: 'C:\<PATH>\pom.xml' is outside repository` error message for the parent `pom.xml`. The `pom.xml` is in place and previously added to the repo. I think git is unable to find it because of the backslash path separator.

I also tried to use the release plugin under default *cmd*. At the end of the release process git push hung. I think, it was wainting for *ssh* password. Under *cmd* I can't configure *ssh* agent so I have to type the password every type interactively. I also tried to add the password as a command line parameter, nothing changed.

I also tried to set `pushChanges` option to `false` to prevent automatic pushing, it also hung.

Relevant part from parent `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
</properties>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://<host>/<project>.git</connection>
    <url><gitweb url></url>
</scm>

<!-- more here -->

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
              <tagNameFormat>
                  release-${timestamp}-v@{project.version}
              </tagNameFormat>
              <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
              <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
              <execution>
              <id>default</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I run this command:

```
mvn release:prepare -B
```

Is there any chance to use release plugin with git on Windows?

Comment: Please provide more detail about the command you're running that produces the error.

Comment: Maybe I run into a bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-581

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `<developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://<host>/<project>.git</developerConnection>`

Comment: Adding developerConnection didn't change anything.